# Hibernate reverse engineering - mapping a table to Java enum

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, hibernate-mapping, jboss-tools

I'm working on a project where I am using JBoss Tools to reverse engineer an MS SqlServer database into Hibernate objects. I am wondering if there is a way to map some of the tables in my schema to Java enums? Can this be configured in the hibernate.reveng.xml file? If so, do you have an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This open issue](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HBX-1029) indicates that enums are not supported by hibernate reveng.